# simple redirect using .htaccess is not working

Tags: javascript, html, .htaccess

I'm trying to create a simple redirection that all my request for `user/55` will be redirected to
`folder2/index2.html`

I'm doing on the tests on localhost running wamp.
My project hierarchy is:

[image]

I defined `.htaccess` like that:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^users/55 folder2/index2.html [R=301,L]
```

My main page is `index1.html` and it looks like that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Index1 page</h1>

    <a href="users/55">go to second page</a>
 </body>
 </html>
```

When I pressed the link there is no redirection instead I get the error:
`The requested URL /redirect/folder1/users/ was not found on this server.`

I enabled mod_rewrite on Apache server and I see not errors in the logs.
What am I doing wrong I try to follow a simple guide and it is not working.

Comment: `.htacess` should be `.htaccess`!

Comment: @Pieter excuse my typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is just because the url in your anchor tag is a relative url.

```
<a href="users/55">go to second page</a>
```

The above will link to `/redirect/folder1/users/`

If you want to link to `/redirect/users` you can try

```
 <a href="/redirect/users/55">go to second page</a>
```

Comment: I did what you suggested but I now get redirected to `http://localhost/folder2/index2.html` instead of `http://localhost/redirect/folder2/index2.html` do you know why?

Comment: thats a problem with your redirect. try changing `RewriteRule ^users/55 folder2/index2.html [R=301,L]` to `RewriteRule ^users/55 redirect/folder2/index2.html [R=301,L]`

Comment: hmmmmm not sure how that is possible. do rewrite rules get applied without restart on your server?

Comment: Yes they do, I also tried to restart the server and clear browsing data noting help is is as if `redirect/` part is being ignored and I'm redirected to `localhost/folder2/index2.html`